# QuickBlox Fatal error

Tags: android, quickblox

Android Studio : 3.0

**Error** : Fatal error in ../../webrtc/api/android/jni/classreferenceholder.cc, line 119       last system error: 88
                                                         # Check failed: !jni->ExceptionCheck()
                                                         # error during FindClass: org/webrtc/Camera1Enumerator

Gradle

```
 compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:2.6.1'
```

Code:

```
 QBRTCSurfaceView surfaceViewLocal = (QBRTCSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.local_video_view);
```

Xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.view.QBRTCSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/remote_video_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.view.QBRTCSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/local_video_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: which version of QuickBlox Android SDK do you use? check that the jni-libs correspond to your virsion of SDK. Additionally specify steps which are you doing for getting this error.

Comment: compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:2.6.1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should search old jni-libs [in releases](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/releases) for your version, [there is zip-archive](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/archive/2.6.1.zip) with needed for you version, just unarchive it and replace your libs with libs from this archive.

Comment: instead of jnilibs replace, changed webrtc:2.6.1 to webrtc:3.3.1